# Dash, Hls and pure Media Source Extension chunkless options

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

i'm experimenting with dash-media source extension and purejs-media source extension and i have seen i have the choice between chunked and inline fragmented videos.

My questions is what codecs are support inline fragmenting, i mean that i have only one file per resolutions and bitrate and one ore two audio files (and no billions of chunks;)) and which ffmpeg options i must use for the options:

I hope and prefer free codes like vorbis,vp8,vp8,ogg,opus and so on and hope all containers (webm) can produce one-segmented-single-files:).

Thx

Answer (score 1):

what you are calling `inline fragmented videos` are just the chunks concatenated into one file, The manifest then records the start position and length of the chunk. The "billions of chunks" tend to be more performant on a CDN.